# How to loop back through and use with user input

Tags: java, loops, joptionpane

So my question is what would be a good way to get a yes no response from a user using j option pane and then if that answer is correct then looping back through my program. Right now my program asks you if you want to sell or buy stuff and then it goes from there. Ideally I would like to ask if you would like to bargain and if you say no the program does not bargain anymore but if you say yes then it asks you if you want to buy or sell, then after that whole thing is done then I would like it to ask if you would like to barter again. Any help is useful thank you.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();

        list.add(new Item("Ketchup", 1.00, 10, 2.00, itemType.FOOD));
        list.add(new Item("Mayo", 2.00, 20, 3.0, itemType.FOOD));
        list.add(new Item("Bleach", 3.00, 30, 4.00, itemType.CLEANING));
        list.add(new Item("Lysol", 4.00, 40, 5.00, itemType.CLEANING));

do{
        int ogresponse = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                "Would you like to barter", "Please select",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);



        String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to buy or sell items?").toLowerCase();


        if (response.equals("sell")) {

            String name_Item = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What would you like to sell (options: Ketchup, Mayo, Bleach, or Lysol?").toLowerCase();
            String qty_Amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much of said item would you like to sell?").toLowerCase();
            int qty_num = Integer.parseInt(qty_Amount);
            sell(list, name_Item, qty_num);

        }else if (response.equals("buy")) {

            String name_Item = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What would you like to buy (options: Ketchup, Mayo, Bleach, or Lysol?").toLowerCase();
            String qty_Amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much of said item would you like to buy?").toLowerCase();
            int qty_num = Integer.parseInt(qty_Amount);
            buy(list, name_Item, qty_num);
}while(ogrepsonse != 0);

        String output = "";
    for(Item i : list) {
        int everything = i.getQty();
        String everything2 = i.getName().toString();

        output += everything +" "+ everything2 + "\n";       
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your current balance is: $" + myBalance + "\n" + "Current stock:" + "\n" + output);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a do/while. Keep iterating as long as the user wants to. Im not sure what ogresponse contains but im assuming 1 for no? Hope this helps.

```
do{
     int ogresponse = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                "Would you like to barter", "Please select",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    System.out.println(ogresponse);


    String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to buy or sell items?").toLowerCase();


    if (response.equals("sell")) {

        String name_Item = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What would you like to sell (options: Ketchup, Mayo, Bleach, or Lysol?").toLowerCase();
        String qty_Amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much of said item would you like to sell?").toLowerCase();
        int qty_num = Integer.parseInt(qty_Amount);
        sell(list, name_Item, qty_num);

    }else if (response.equals("buy")) {

        String name_Item = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What would you like to buy (options: Ketchup, Mayo, Bleach, or Lysol?").toLowerCase();
        String qty_Amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much of said item would you like to buy?").toLowerCase();
        int qty_num = Integer.parseInt(qty_Amount);
        buy(list, name_Item, qty_num);
       }
}while(ogresponse !=1);
```

Comment: thank you for your comment and i know im replying late. I did what you said I think it is causing errors else where on my program. I get this error on the line "your current balance is"

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert "while ( Expression ) ;" to complete 
  DoStatement
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

Comment: Hi @VictorAlam I adjusted my solution and should work for you now. There was a bracket missing from the last if/else compound statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try following approach:

```
do {
  ogresponse = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to barter", "Please select", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
  System.out.println(ogresponse);

  String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to buy or sell items?").toLowerCase();
  if (response.equals("sell")) {
    String name_Item = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What would you like to sell (options: Ketchup, Mayo, Bleach, or Lysol?").toLowerCase();
    String qty_Amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much of said item would you like to sell?").toLowerCase();
    int qty_num = Integer.parseInt(qty_Amount);
    sell(list, name_Item, qty_num);
  } else if (response.equals("buy")) {
    String name_Item = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What would you like to buy (options: Ketchup, Mayo, Bleach, or Lysol?").toLowerCase();
    String qty_Amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much of said item would you like to buy?").toLowerCase(); 
    int qty_num = Integer.parseInt(qty_Amount);
    buy(list, name_Item, qty_num);
  }
} while (ogresponse != 1);
```

Comment: Hey there thanks for the reply but this does not work. It prompts the user whether or not they would like to barter twice but then it goes through the loop no matter what

Comment: Scratch that it does not come up twice anymore but if you hit no the program does not end it just goes through the program and then ends prematurely. It seems that if you hit no the program goes forever

Comment: @VictorAlam that is because a no response will return 1, I fixed that in mine, try it in yours.